# Make image caption cover the entire image on hover

Tags: html, css

Currently I am using css in squarespace to try and make image captions cover the entire image on hover, but because of some of squarespace's code I can make it cover the bottom portion of the image.

Here is the website page I am editing:

https://baikart.com/3rdall

And here is the code I have so far to change the caption:

```
.sqs-block-image .image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-overlay-hover .image-caption-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    transform: translate(-0%,-0%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0%,-0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-0%,-0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-0%,-0%);   
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `max-height` from here

```
.sqs-block-image .image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-overlay-hover:hover .image-caption-wrapper {
    max-height: 75%;
}
```

and set `height: 100%`.

Comment: I don't think OP is setting that style, it's in squarespace so they need to override it with something.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding max-height: 100%; but it doesn't work. I did notice however that there is a box-sizing: border-box; which if I cancel out in chrome dev tools it lowers the caption wrapper a little, but not all the way to the bottom of the image. I am also worried because once I solve this problem I still need to be able to click the caption and have it link to the same hyperlink in the image

Answer (score 0):

When you look using element inspector in chrome dev tools or something you can see that there is a max-height: 75% being applied to the caption class. You would need to change this to 100% in your css.

This is what is in element inspector

```
.sqs-block-image .image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-overlay-hover:hover .image-caption-wrapper {
    max-height: 75%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```